# Printing the ≤ symbol on a PDF file using JagPDF libraries

Tags: c++, pdf, unicode

I am creating a PDF file using JagPDF and I am trying to print the ≤ symbol like this:

```
pdf::Document doc(pdf::create_file("report.pdf"));
doc.page_start(792,612);   
pdf::Font font = doc.font_load("standard; name=Times-Roman; size=12");
doc.page().canvas().text_font(font);
doc.page().canvas().color("f", 0);
doc.page().canvas().text_rendering_mode("f");
doc.page().canvas().text(100, 300, "PEP ≤ 90");
doc.page_end();
doc.finalize();
```

that prints out

```
PEP ? 90
```

I tried reading the documentation and they say something about Unicode but couldn't understand how they work, it must be easy and just something I am missing. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The [JagPDF spec](http://www.jagpdf.org/doc/jagpdf/reference/langspec.htm) says you can add the encoding to the parameter for `doc.font_load`, so that would be `doc.font_load("standard; enc=utf-8; name=Times-Roman; size=12");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood as much, what I don't get is once I set the encoder how do I call that specific symbol? they have as an example unicode_text = u'\u017elu\u0165ou\u010dk\u00fd k\u016f\u0148 \u00fap\u011bl' but when I try to set a variable this way it gives me an error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JagPDF, but the example you have there is not the right syntax for C++. Use double quotes.

Comment: @DiegoFernandoPava that doesn't work because `''` is used for characters. The compiler will immediately warn you the issue. For example gcc will output something like "error: too many characters in character constant". You must use `u"\u017elu\u0165ou\u010dk\u00fd k\u016f\u0148 \u00fap\u011bl"` instead. And **always read compiler warnings**, they're very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JagPDF but `"PEP ≤ 90"` should work fine, provided that you saved the source code as UTF-8 and the library also expects an UTF-8 string. You can also use `"PEP \u2264 90"` with `\uXXXX` is the escape sequence for the code point U+XXXX, but that's obviously less readable

According to the documentation you can set the encoding and output the text with the below snippet

> ```
> font = doc.font_load("file=DejaVuSans.ttf; size=14; enc=utf-8")
> canvas.text_font(font)
> text = unicode_text.encode('utf8')
> canvas.text(50, 780, text)
> ```
>
> http://www.jagpdf.org/doc/jagpdf/usersguide/text.htm

You also need to use a TrueType or OpenType font because there's a note under Type 1 font in the same page

> Even though JagPDF allows to change the font built-in encoding to UTF-8, we are in practice limited to the Latin alphabet, because of the character set used by the standard fonts.

If you use C++11 and up (which you should) then you can force the encoding as UTF-8 with either of the below

```
u8"PEP ≤ 90"
u8"PEP \U00002264 90"
u8"PEP \u2264 90"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
doc.page().canvas().text(100, 300, "PEP \U+2264 90");
```

Comment: `\U+2664` is wrong. `\U` escape doesn't go with `+`